# Counting occurrences of Values for each string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I got a file on the form

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[String])] = MapPartitionsRDD[364]
```

Which is a file where i got a couple of keys (`string`), and many values per key (`Array[String]`).
I want to be able to count the number of each occurrence in the Value for each separate string. I have tried different approaches but I haven't found anything that works yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can unfold the data and produce an `RDD[((String, String), Int)]`, where each row is a single occurrence of a pair of your unfolded key-value and the number of times it happens (just 1 while unfolding). Then, you just need to `reduceByKey` and sum the occurrences.

```
rdd
    .flatMap { case (key, values) => values.map(value => (key, value) -> 1) }
    .reduceByKey(_+_)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupBy` and `mapValues` to *get the occurence counts of each strings* in the `Array[String]`

Lets say you have `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[String])]` as

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("str1", Array("test1", "test2", "test1", "test2", "test3")),
  ("str2", Array("test2", "test2", "test12", "test2", "test5"))
))
//rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[String])]
```

As I explained above you can do

```
val counted = rdd.map(x => (x._1, x._2.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)))
//counted: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int])]
```

If you print them

```
counted.foreach(println)
//(str1,Map(test2 -> 2, test1 -> 2, test3 -> 1))
//(str2,Map(test2 -> 3, test5 -> 1, test12 -> 1))
//res0: Unit = ()
```

I hope the answer is helpful